# How to find yarn application statistics from command line in human readable format

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I have an application with some id like `application_2019xxxxxxxxxxxxx`

I'm able to find it's statistics with command `yarn application -status application_2019xxxxxxxxxxxxx` which gives output in key-value format.

The issue here is some of the fields are not in human readable format, e.g. start time and end time of application are in unix epoch format. This is causing trouble in automation of script.

Can anyone please help how to get all values in human readable format ? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to convert that data into human readable format some of them are below:

```
mysql> select from_unixtime(floor(1517874876754/1000));
+------------------------------------------+
| from_unixtime(floor(1517874876754/1000)) |
+------------------------------------------+
| 2018-02-05 18:54:36                      |
+------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

$ awk '{print strftime("%c", ( 1517874876754 + 500 ) / 1000 )}'
Mon 05 Feb 2018 06:54:37 PM EST

$ date -d @$(  echo "(1517874876754+ 500) / 1000" | bc)
Mon Feb  5 18:54:37 EST 2018
```

Comment: that's helpful :) but i'm looking for something which can print values directly in human readable format and avoiding extra lines of code for conversion.

Comment: @Vin I noticed you are doing two different calculation on mysql and awk/date. Is there a reason why to add 500 in value and then divide by 1000. Also why are we dividing it by 1000? Can you also provide some links where such tit-bits can be found. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @MuditSingal I'm glad you asked that question so let me clear your doubt .I am adding 500 in that epoch time `1517874876754+500` because I need it in EST time zone that value depends on the time zone if you are on a different time zone that value(500) will change accordingly. Moreover, I am dividing by 1000 coz I don't want the miliseconds  if I don't divide it by 1000 the value would be  `Monday, February 5, 2018 11:54:36.754 PM EST` hope you get it and here is the link where you can try different numbers and formats https://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: @Vin Since EST is lagging by 5hrs from UTC shouldn't the time in milliseconds be subtracted before conversion? I am converting using linux date cmd

Answer (score 0):

Try this : `perl -leprint   \ scalar\  localtime\   epoch time`

and `date -d @ epoch time`